# C# Add values to List<Borrower>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Borrower>` called `BorrowerList`which is supposed to contain a list of Borrowers' names and the title of the book they borrowed.

This happens when a borrower is dequeued from `BorrowerQueue` and a book is popped from `BookStack`.

What I want to happen is that the values form `BorrowerQueue` and `Bookstack` be added to `BorrowerList` like in this [sample from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx). However I do not completely understand how it is done. Help is much appreciated.

```
 var reader = BorrowerQueue.Dequeue(); //person gets dequeued from line
 var books = BookStack.Pop(); // book gets popped from stack and associated to reader

 BorrowerList.Add(new Borrower(reader.ToString()) {}); // what to do here?
```

Goal :

```
{[name1, Book], [name2, Book] .... }
```

This is my class for `Borrower`:

```
class Borrower : IEnumerable<Borrower>
{
    private string name;
    private Book b;

    public Borrower(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Book getBook()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setBook(Book b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

`Book` class:

```
class Book
{
    private string title, author;
    private int ISBN;

    public Book(string t, string a, int i)
    {
        this.title = t;
        this.author = a;
        this.ISBN = i;
    }

    public string getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public string getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public int getISBN()
    {
        return ISBN;
    }
```

Comment: Add a second `Book` parameter to the `Borrower` constructor and pass the book in through that.

Comment: Although perhaps for this case, having a `Dictionary<string, List<Book>>` might be more appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to learn about properties in C#, and C# naming conventions. Currently your code looks very much more like Java than C#.

Comment: I know right. It's been 2 years since I had to use C# for class. Then a year ago I had to take Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your property getters and setters to standard properties. C# compiler will automatically convert them get/set functions. Your class should look like this:

```
class Borrower
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public Borrower(string n)
    {
        //Since C# 6.0, read-only properties can be set in the constructor
        this.Name = n; 
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is to set Book property when you dequeue:

```
var reader = BorrowerQueue.Dequeue(); //person gets dequeued from line
var books = BookStack.Pop(); // book gets popped from stack and associated to reader
BorrowerList.Add(new Borrower(reader.ToString()) { Book = book });
```

Comment: This looks good but I would say that `Name` should be an auto property as well. Since C# 6.0 one may write `string Name { get; }` and initialize it from the constructor.

Comment: Agreed, making `Name` be `{ get; private set; }` would result in cleaner code overall. (Not to mention that currently the constructor sets `Name` which doesn't have a setter and so would not compile.)

Comment: @AluanHaddad I was referring to dotNET's current code, in which `Name` is not an auto property, so doing that wouldn't work.

Comment: I have an error on `{ Book = books}` part

`Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'ConsoleApplication3.Book'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @Kevin What type is `BorrowerQueue` and `BookStack`? Are you using a non-generic `Stack` and `Queue`?

Comment: @Kevin Any particular reason why you aren't using the generic versions?

Comment: for project specs

Comment: @Kevin If possible, use the generic versions (they are objectively better in every regard). Otherwise, add a `(Book)` cast to the assignment. (i.e. `Book = (Book)books`

Comment: follow up question: how can I access a single element of `List<Borrower>` once it's been populated with data?

Comment: Also when I compile and run I get 2 errors: `Error 1 'ConsoleApplication3.Borrower' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'`

`Error 2 'ConsoleApplication3.Borrower' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication3.Borrower>.GetEnumerator()'`

Comment: I have updated my code. Any class `X` should normally never implement `IEnumerable<X>`, it doesn't make sense. You should store your Borrowers in a separate collection, which you already seem to be doing.